# In quartz how to fetch/delete jobs by using name macther class?

Tags: java, clojure, quartz-scheduler, quartzite

I am using Quartz 2.1.7 (In Clojure using [Quartzite](http://clojurequartz.info/articles/guides.html) library).
I have jobs that have ids named like "abc/xyz". And I would like to

- Fetch all jobs whose id starts with "abc"
- Delete all jobs whose id starts with "abc"

I saw the Quartz API, there is a scheduler function called [getJobKeys](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#getJobKeys(org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher)) which takes a GroupMatcher and will fetch keys for matching group. But I would like match on ids not groups as groups are common.

There is a [NameMatcher] class which works like GroupMatcher but I couldn't find a way to use it to fetch all jobs in a scheduler.

One way I can think of is to fetch all jobs within a group and check if each object fetched if it returns true for [isMatch](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/matchers/StringMatcher.html#isMatch(T)) for my NameMatcher object.

But I am wondering if there is a more cleaner way to do this?

Thanks.